# How to use _IEAction() to perform a secondary click?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, autoit

How to perform a secondary click on an object (tag) using IE.au3 UDF? This is my code:

```
Local $oTags = _IETagNameGetCollection($oTable, 'i')
For $oTag In $oTags
   If StringInStr($oTag.outerHTML, "Number column menu") > 0 Then
      $oTag.fireEvent("onmousedown")
      $oTag.fireEvent("onmouseup")
      $oTag.fireEvent("click")
      ;_IEAction($oTag, "click")
      MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Result", "Clicked on: " & $oTag.outerHTML)
   EndIf
Next
```

I managed to find the `<i>` tag to click but need to perform a *right* click by object (tag) and action as parameter. `MouseClick()` only takes coordinates as parameter, not objects.

Comment: Couldn't you use [_IEGetObjByName](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IEGetObjByName.htm)?

Comment: Why do you need to right click? If you can explain it there might be another way where you don't have to right click anymore using autoit.. but as of now I can't say anything.. If you want to save the page or an image then tell it..

Comment: The <i> tag i want to click has two behaviors, click (left) works as "sort" and the right click shows a context menu (html) which has the element I want to click in order to download a file, i have to perform that click because if I don't do that, the HTML menu never appears (it's created at runtime).